# Issue with the payment flow using selenium webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, credit-card

I have a scenario where I need to automate the payment page.

I need to enter the credit card details, but the thing is when I use send_keys method to type the text, it doesn't take the full card number though it only takes the first three characters and the last one.

This is the code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_number")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[5]), Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_name")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[6]))
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_month")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[7]))
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_year")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[8]))
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_verification_value")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[9]), Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

I read that one solution is to inject the credit card number with Javascript, basically something like execute_script with a string and argument. All has to be in Python.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
change in to python it should be the same

public void runScript(Driver driver, String script) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = null;
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            try {
                logger.info(script);
                js.executeScript(script);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info(e + " " + script);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.

Here is what I'm using now

elem = driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('checkout_credit_card_number').value+='" + sys.argv[5] + "'");

Weird enough that the previous method started working again.

Comment: happy the hear that :)